# Button is not redirecting me to the next "page"

Tags: html, cordova

I am currently making an app. I would like to redirect the user to the next page but it is mainly just pressing the button and you would be brought over to the next set of details. It should still remain on the same html link. However, when I press the button, nothing seems to be working.

```
<div data-role="page" id="mainpage">
    <h1>
        <b>Converter App</b>
    </h1>
</div>
<div class="app">
    <a href="#convertingpage" class="ui-btn">Convert</a>
    <div data-role="page" id="convertingpage">
        <p> stuff on my second page</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am sorry if this sounds rather complex or hard to comprehend.

Comment: I dont see a button in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming convertingpage is an HTML page which is in the same location of Main page. ( if different than hmtl change the html suffix accordingly)

When you specify  href="#convertingpage" it means to look on the **same page** for an element with  an ID of convertingpage.

If you want to be redirected to other page use:

```
 <a href="convertingpage.html" class="ui-btn">Convert</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay on the same html page, but be redirected to a different section of the page, as you appear to be trying to do in your example, you want to be using an anchor.

In your example,

```
<div data-role="page" id="convertingpage">
    <p> stuff on my second page</p>
</div>
```

you tried to do this with the id of you div, but to make an anchor you need to use an `<a>` tag.

Here's how I would do it, trying to stay as similar to your page a possible.

```
<div data-role="page" id="mainpage">
    <h1>
        <b>Converter App</b>
    </h1>
</div>
<div class="app">
    <a href="#convertingpage" class="ui-btn">Convert</a>
    <div data-role="page">
    <a id="convertingpage"></a>
        <p> stuff on my second page</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note the `<a id="convertingpage"></a>` anchor that the link redirects to. Also, I removed the `id` attribute from your second page div, so if you need it for styling, you should replace it.